# MySQL, filter in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, grouping, where-clause

I am working on a MySQl database and have something like a tracking system for our invetory. With the inventoryNumber of the device, the person who got it, when he got it and when he returned it. If the returned column is null, then the person still has the device.

```
|InventoryNumber | user  | receive    | returned   |
+----------------+-------+------------+------------+
| X1             | Mark  | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-03 |
| X1             | Mark  | 2017-01-03 | null       |
| X2             | Frank | 2017-01-01 | null       |
```

now I want to know which devices are not in use. So first I have to `GROUP BY InventoryNumber` but "show" the `null`. Afterwords I have to filter `WHERE returned IS NOT NULL`

I know how to do that seperately, but after the `GROUP BY` he takes always the first row and not the one with the `null`, so I can't use `WHERE`.

I hope you understand my problem and can help me.

Comment: can you provide your code so far? if you already have the parts, it should be possible with a subquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return all numbers where there is not a single row which is NULL. A quick reminder: WHERE filters rows HAVING filters groups.

```
SELECT InventoryNumber 
GROUP BY InventoryNumber 
HAVING SUM(returned IS NULL)=0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sub query with `NOT IN`, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE returned IS NOT NULL
AND InventoryNumber NOT IN (
   SELECT InventoryNumber 
   FROM table
   WHERE returned IS NULL
);
```

Comment: I would like to avoid multiple select statements. nevertheless thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select
`InventoryNumber`
from
`track`
where
`returned` is NOT NULL
group by `InventoryNumber`;
```